# Can't authenticate with Dropbox on Android

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm trying to authenticate a user on Dropbox using a generic class for OAuth. It seems that Dropbox is not returning the token-secret like the API says.

```
private CommonsHttpOAuthProvider mOAuthProvider;
private CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer mOAuthConsumer;

mOAuthConsumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(mConsumerKey, mConsumerSecret);
//mConsumerKey and Secret are provided by Dropbox

mOAuthProvider = new CommonsHttpOAuthProvider(
mRequestTokenEndpointUrl, mAccessTokenEndpointUrl, mAuthorizationWebsiteUrl);

String url = null;
try {
    url = mOAuthProvider.retrieveRequestToken(mOAuthConsumer, mCallback);
}catch(Exception e){}
```

The API says that url should now contain the token/token_secret pair. However, the url looks like this:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=xxxxxx&oauth_callback=xxxxx
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using the oauth-signpost library.  The URL you get isn't to retrieve the token and secret.  Rather, you must use that URL to launch a browser window to let the user authenticate himself.  To retrieve the token and secret returned by DropBox, you must do this:

```
String url = null;
try {
    url = mOAuthProvider.retrieveRequestToken(mOAuthConsumer, mCallback);

    //Retrieve token and secret here
    String token = mOAuthConsumer.getToken();
    String secret = mOAuthConsumer.getTokenSecret();
}
catch(Exception e){}
```

You can then launch the browser window with the URL you got from the call to retrieveRequestToken(), for example:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
```

One tip though, please make sure you save your request token and secret before launching the browser window (I suggest saving them in *SharedPreferences*) because once you exit your activity, your ***mOAuthConsumer*** instance will be lost. You will then have to recreate ***mOAuthConsumer*** and set the request token and secret you retrieved in order to then retrieve the ACCESS token and secret.

Good luck!